# x-ray.js grabbing class attributes and returning it

Tags: x-ray

I am using x-ray scraping tool to scrape some fun sites but it seem that I can't figure out how I can grab the class attributes.

Also, do you guys know the good cheatsheet for this module?

Answer (score 0):

You can select classes using the class dot '.' notation.

X-Ray is simple to understand if you spend time reading thru the javascript files contained there in. The github site also provide a handy guide on web scraping using X-RAY.

Simply google "x-ray web scraping tutorial".

Hope this answer helps you out. Let me know if you need any detailed explanations and/or links.

Cheers,
Sylvery